# why doesn't my code work when i have a subfolder statring with numeric values in PATH?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, path, glob, os.path

I am reading a folder of multiple images and here's the part of code where i read the folder specified in path,

```
path =  'C:\main\folder\sub-folder\08001\V.1\abc\2015'

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.tif') ):

    Img = gdal.Open( infile )
    if Img is None:
      print 'Unable to open Input Image'
      sys.exit(1)
```

... so the code doesn't work as in it doesn't read any files in that folder but it also doesn't throw any error. I figured that it's not working only when the path has any of the Sub-folder's name starting with numeric values.

Here Path = 'C:\main\folder\sub-folder\08001\V.1\abc\2015' and as you can see it has two Sub-folder's (08001 and 2015) starting with numeric values.

** It works absolutely fine when there are no such sub-folder's starting with numeric values.

Why does this happen and how can i fix this ??
Also how can i automatically look into any sub-folder's if exist in the original path provided ?

when i look for that path in command shell, here's what it shows.

```
>>> path =  'C:\P\S\Mo\C\08008\L\V.1R\2015'
>>> path
'C:\\P\\S\\Mo\\C\x008008\\L\\V.1R\x815'
```

Comment: See also [Python 2.6: “Couldn't open image” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718969/python-2-6-couldnt-open-image-error), which had the same underlying problem but with non-numeric paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in your string:

```
path =  'C:\\P\\S\\Mo\\C\\08008\\L\\V.1R\\2015'
```

It's just coincidence that your path works when there are no numbers in it. If you had a path with a folder that began with `a`, `b`, `n`, or [certain other letters](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), it wouldn't work either.

A backslash followed by three numbers is parsed as an octal number whose value to insert into the string. The first such sequence is `\080`. `8` is not a valid octal digit, so Python stops parsing octal after the zero. This is displayed in hexadecimal as `\x00` in your output. The second sequence is `\201`, and octal 201 is equal to hexadecimal 81—`\x81`.

Alternatively, you can use a raw string:

```
path =  r'C:\P\S\Mo\C\08008\L\V.1R\2015'
```

The `r` before the string literal tells Python not to parse escape sequences in the string. When working with Windows paths, this can make your paths look much nicer.

A third possibility is to use forward slashes instead of backslashes in your path string:

```
path =  'C:/P/S/Mo/C/08008/L/V.1R/2015'
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank You very much for the info, that gives a better understanding!

Comment: Any idea on how can i also read the subfolders in the main path provided using the same gob.glob ?

Comment: A Google search for "Python glob.glob recursive" found a previous SO question, [How can I search sub-folders using glob.glob module in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python).