# My Image is not loading via pygame

Tags: python, pygame

down as you can see, I've just copied my game from Python using Pygame.. Now, the 'Game' won't load my images, I've put them in the same folder.

I really need help, I have tried several things, like relocating the folder and stuff.

Also, i am very new to python.

```
# This is my first game demonstration

import pygame, sys, random
from pygame import *
pygame.init()


def game():
    #make window called screen and initialize the background

    width, height = 600, 400
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("My Star Catcher Game")
    background=pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
    background=pygame.transform.scale(background,(width, height))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    #load target image and player

    target=pygame.image.load("star.png")
    target=pygame.transform.scale(target,(20,20))
    target.pos=target.get_rect_()
    screen.blit(target,targetpos)

    player = pygame.image.load("myplayer.png")
    player=pygame.transform.scale(player, (30,30))
    px,py=width/2,height/2
    screren.blit(player, (px,py))

    movex = movey = 0

    speed=[random.randint(1,3),random.randint(1,4)]


    # running of the game loop
    while True:
        #image display updates
        targetpos.move_ip(speed)
        screren.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(target, targetpos)
        screren.blit(player, (px,py))

        pygame.display.update()

        #keyboard and/or mouse movements
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = 2
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = -2
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    movey = -2
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    movey = 2
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = 0`enter code here`
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = -0
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    movey = -0
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    movey = 0
                    px = px + movex
                    py = py + movey



        if targetpos[0]+20>width or targetpos[0]<0:
            speed[0]= -speed[0]

        if targetpos[1]>height or targetpos[1]<0:
            speed[1]= -speed[1]
            targetpos[1]+=speed[1]


enter code here

# python's way of running the main routine
if __name__=="__main__":
    game()
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages when you run this? It will be very easy to solve your problem if you post this, most specifically the "somethingException" that most likely it says in the error text.

Answer (score 0):

Are your files in the same directory?

Read these:

[Why are my pygame images not loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188670/why-are-my-pygame-images-not-loading)

[Python 2.6: "Couldn't open image" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718969/python-2-6-couldnt-open-image-error)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote '**screren**' twice instead of '**screen**'

```
    targetpos.move_ip(speed)
    screren.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(target, targetpos)
    screren.blit(player, (px,py))

    pygame.display.update()
```

There are also a few more syntax errors, be sure to go over your code looking for them when you receive an error.